# How can I initialize this structure?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, clang

I got compiler errors in clang so I started to reduce a minimal test case. But for most reduced test case GCC tells that it contains a syntax error. How can I init this structure?

```
template<typename F>
struct Item
{
  F *foo(); // with std::function clang also crash
};

template<typename F>
struct Container
{
  static const Item<F> items[];
};


template<typename F>
const Item<F> Container<F>::items[] =
{
  {  []() -> F { } }
  // {{  []() -> F { } }} this also wrong
};

template struct Container<int>;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

GCC said:

```
clangBug.cc: In instantiation of ‘const Item<int> Container<int>::items []’:
clangBug.cc:24:17:   required from here
clangBug.cc:17:15: error: too many initializers for ‘const Item<int>’
```

Clang master HEAD (040cd82aadd48ba50e9742881d648d53ddd2a6c9) crash with:

```
3  libc.so.6       0x00007f304c590037 gsignal + 55
4  libc.so.6       0x00007f304c593698 abort + 328
5  libc.so.6       0x00007f304c588e03
6  libc.so.6       0x00007f304c588eb2
7  clang           0x0000000000cd823e clang::Sema::InstantiateClassMembers(clang::SourceLocation, clang::CXXRecordDecl*, clang::MultiLevelTemplateArgumentList const&, clang::TemplateSpecializationKind) + 1646
8  clang           0x0000000000cd82f4 clang::Sema::InstantiateClassTemplateSpecializationMembers(clang::SourceLocation, clang::ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl*, clang::TemplateSpecializationKind) + 68
9  clang           0x0000000000c6c341 clang::Sema::ActOnExplicitInstantiation(clang::Scope*, clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation, unsigned int, clang::SourceLocation, clang::CXXScopeSpec const&, clang::OpaquePtr<clang::TemplateName>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation, llvm::MutableArrayRef<clang::ParsedTemplateArgument>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::AttributeList*) + 2225
10 clang           0x000000000097cb65 clang::Parser::ParseClassSpecifier(clang::tok::TokenKind, clang::SourceLocation, clang::DeclSpec&, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::AccessSpecifier, bool, clang::Parser::DeclSpecContext, clang::Parser::ParsedAttributesWithRange&) + 5733
11 clang           0x0000000000962dd7 clang::Parser::ParseDeclarationSpecifiers(clang::DeclSpec&, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::AccessSpecifier, clang::Parser::DeclSpecContext, clang::Parser::LateParsedAttrList*) + 3511
12 clang           0x00000000009c4a98 clang::Parser::ParseSingleDeclarationAfterTemplate(unsigned int, clang::Parser::ParsedTemplateInfo const&, clang::ParsingDeclRAIIObject&, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::AccessSpecifier, clang::AttributeList*) + 632
13 clang           0x00000000009c3fda clang::Parser::ParseExplicitInstantiation(unsigned int, clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceLocation&, clang::AccessSpecifier) + 154
```

Comment: reporting bugs is for the upstream dev channels, also a member [] is not wellformed without dimensions IYAM

Comment: I subbmited now: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17500

Comment: @sehe: hx, but with [1] syntax happen the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want `Item<F>::foo` to be data member that points to a function taking no arguments, and returning `F` by value. What you have right now is a declaration of a member function `foo` that takes no arguments, and returns `F *`. Change the definition to:

```
template<typename F>
struct Item
{
  F (*foo)();
};
```

Also, as sehe says in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235459/how-can-i-initialize-this-structure/19235702#comment28471443_19235459), I think you'll have to provide a size for the `Container<F>::items` array. And the lambda in the initializer needs to returns a value.

```
template<typename F>
const Item<F> Container<F>::items[N] =
{
  {  []() -> F { return F(); } }
};
```